# Old bytecode offsets after instrumentation using ASM in Java

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I want to print the bytecode offset where the exception happened at runtime. I have the JVMTI patch to do it. But when I instrument the code using ASM the printed bytecode offset for the exception is different because of the instrumentation. Is there a way to get the old bytecode offset of the instruction after the instrumentation is done? Or is there any alternative way to do it?

Here is an example class:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Before exception!!!");
    System.out.println(5/0);
    System.out.println("After exception!!!");
  }
}
```

The JVMTI Patch is as follows:

```
#include <jvmti.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static jclass Exception;
static jfieldID detailMessage;

void JNICALL VMInit(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* env, jthread thread) {
    jclass localE = env->FindClass("java/lang/Exception");
    Exception = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(localE);

    jclass Throwable = env->FindClass("java/lang/Throwable");
    detailMessage = env->GetFieldID(Throwable, "detailMessage", "Ljava/lang/String;");
}

void JNICALL ExceptionCallback(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, JNIEnv* env, jthread thread,
                               jmethodID method, jlocation location, jobject exception,
                               jmethodID catch_method, jlocation catch_location) {
    if (env->IsInstanceOf(exception, Exception)) {
        char buf[32];
        sprintf(buf, "location=%ld", (long)location);
        env->SetObjectField(exception, detailMessage, env->NewStringUTF(buf));
    }
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, char* options, void* reserved) {
    jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
    vm->GetEnv((void**)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);

    jvmtiCapabilities capabilities = {0};
    capabilities.can_generate_exception_events = 1;
    jvmti->AddCapabilities(&capabilities);

    jvmtiEventCallbacks callbacks = {0};
    callbacks.VMInit = VMInit;
    callbacks.Exception = ExceptionCallback;
    jvmti->SetEventCallbacks(&callbacks, sizeof(callbacks));
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_VM_INIT, NULL);
    jvmti->SetEventNotificationMode(JVMTI_ENABLE, JVMTI_EVENT_EXCEPTION, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

To compile the patch use the command:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -I/path/to/java/jdk1.7.0_80/include -I/path/to/java/jdk1.7.0_80/include/linux -o libJVMTIPatch.so JVMTIPatch.cpp
```

To run use the '-agentpath' option:

```
java -agentpath:/path/to/libJVMTIPatch.so Test
```

The output will be:

```
Before exception!!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: location=13
at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

Where "location=13" is the bytecode offset where the exception happened.

```
class Test {
  Test();
  Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   3: ldc           #3                  // String Before exception!!!
   5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   8: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  11: iconst_5
  12: iconst_0
  13: idiv
  14: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  17: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  20: ldc           #6                  // String After exception!!!
  22: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  25: return
}
```

But when the class Test is instrumented for some purpose by ASM the bytecode offset of idiv instruction is changed and hence the output is different as expected:

```
public class Test {
Test();
Code:
   0: invokestatic  #39                 // Method rr/state/ShadowThread.getCurrentShadowThread:()Lrr/state/ShadowThread;
   3: astore_1
   4: aload_1
   5: astore_1
   6: ldc           #41                 // String Test.<init>()V 0
   8: aload_1
   9: invokestatic  #47                 // Method rr/tool/RREventGenerator.bbEnter:(Ljava/lang/String;Lrr/state/ShadowThread;)V
  12: aload_0
  13: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  16: aload_0
  17: ldc           #49                 // String ALOAD 0
  19: aload_1
  20: invokestatic  #53                 // Method rr/tool/RREventGenerator.objIdPrint:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lrr/state/ShadowThread;)V
  23: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: invokestatic  #39                 // Method rr/state/ShadowThread.getCurrentShadowThread:()Lrr/state/ShadowThread;
   3: astore_1
   4: aload_1
   5: astore_1
   6: ldc           #55                 // String Test.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V 0
   8: aload_1
   9: invokestatic  #47                 // Method rr/tool/RREventGenerator.bbEnter:(Ljava/lang/String;Lrr/state/ShadowThread;)V
  12: aload_0
  13: ldc           #49                 // String ALOAD 0
  15: aload_1
  16: invokestatic  #53                 // Method rr/tool/RREventGenerator.objIdPrint:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Lrr/state/ShadowThread;)V
  19: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  22: ldc           #56                 // int 0
  24: invokestatic  #61                 // Method rr/instrument/classes/ClassInitNotifier.__$rr_static_access:(I)V
  27: ldc           #3                  // String Before exception!!!
  29: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  32: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  35: ldc           #56                 // int 0
  37: invokestatic  #61                 // Method rr/instrument/classes/ClassInitNotifier.__$rr_static_access:(I)V
  40: iconst_5
  41: iconst_0
  42: idiv
  43: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  46: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  49: ldc           #56                 // int 0
  51: invokestatic  #61                 // Method rr/instrument/classes/ClassInitNotifier.__$rr_static_access:(I)V
  54: ldc           #6                  // String After exception!!!
  56: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  59: return
}
```

Hence the output becomes:

```
Before exception!!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: location=42
at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

I want to get the offset before the instrumentation was done.

Comment: You will get much better responses when you add the source code of a minimal program which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Bytecode offsets is one of the things, the ASM library does hide from the developer, as the abstraction, `Label`, allows to smoothly use all features requiring offsets throughout the transformed code. E.g., the line numbers are still reported correctly after the transformation. Even if you manage to create some mapping table from old to new offsets, how do you intent to pass it to the native code?

Comment: Thank you @Holger for your reply. I want to get the old offset to be just printed. This printed information will the input to some other pass which requires the offsets from original program.